# How to save large photos with web safe colors?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, color, color-management, color-spaces

When I'm done in photoshop I always use save for web to take care of color management so it looks the way I want in the jpeg, but it won't let me save photos any larger than 8191 pixels on a side, which in this case locks it at 53% of the total image size.

How should I do web safe color management and jpeg compression and blur on images larger than 8191 px? Even for an image that'll never be posted, it might be nice to have the jpeg for display on my computer, for example.

Edit: I used save for web normally, and yet it seems to [have actually saved it at full resolution?](https://www.flickr.com/photos/111798824@N07/15556512623/sizes/o/) any ideas why?

Comment: What does that have to do with [web safe colors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_safe_colors#Web-safe_colors)? Jpeg will not use 216 color (obsolete) palette, but is 24-bit color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Save for web and devices..." is all about file size management. It's hard to argue that a 45MP image (2:3 aspect ratio with the long side at 8191) is slightly too small for a web page (yet, at  least). And convenience, I suppose, since it offers one-stop shopping for a bunch of things that would otherwise be separate menu options.

You can use **Image→Mode...** to change to 8-bit colour depth if you're not already there.

**Edit→Convert to Profile...** will get you to sRGB if that's what you want. You will need to choose the appropriate out-of-gamut conversion mode; either Perceptual or Relative Colorimetric will be appropriate for a photograph, depending on which colours are out, how much of the image they occupy, and by how much. Perceptual affects more of the image, keeping things in better overall balance, but it may cause unwanted colour shifts. Relative Colorimetric mostly affects only the tones that are out of gamut, but it can leave the things that were changed standing out like a sore thumb sometimes. The other two options are never appropriate for a photo; pretend they don't exist.

Use **Image→Size...** to scale (not needed if you want full-rez), and **File→Save As...** to create the JPEG. You would need to "save as a copy" if you don't first flatten the image. And, if desired, leave out the colour profile, which will take up a lot of space in a small image, but will be negligible on larger ones. You should only consider that option safe if the image is saved as sRGB.

The only thing you'd be missing is the option to leave out (or selectively include) EXIF info. You can manage that in another program post-save if you want. And you can always make it an action or script if there's too much clicking for your tastes.

Comment: Thanks! Also, it's not 45mb, it's a very long and skinny panorama, which is why I was annoyed by the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "save for web", just use "save as" -> "jpeg" instead. You can save it at any size you want then.

Comment: Save as does not do any of the things I asked about, mainly detailed compression controls and blur, color depth and color space management.

Comment: color space is not something you fiddle with: just use sRGB or whatever your application needs.  Interactively fiddling with the compression level vs file size is handy, I admit, but not as critical as it used to be since larger files are tolerated.  As far as finding the highest compression number, you could find it using a crop of the real picture, then use that value for the whole picture... except Save for Web uses a different scale :( and a different engine, for that matter.  Slicing is your best bet anyway, and allows for faster page showing since it will show the first chunk earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the slice featute in *save for web* and save it as a set of tiles of reasonable size.